# ubuntu freezing problem when running virtual machine

Tags: updates, virtualbox, freeze

I'm using Virtualbox running kali on it, after the latest upgrade of ubuntu 16.04 it's freezing when I run any virtual machine, does anyone have that problem?

Comment: Check you RAM size when you run it with `free -h`

Comment: I have 8 gigs of ddr4 and there isn't any thing running with it and set the virtual machine to 4gigs